# How to make dayJS accept the passed in dateString as UTC?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, dayjs

I'm trying to pass dayJS a date / time string and convert it to NY timezone. The issue I'm having is that the date / time string I pass it is being interpreted as Eastern Time (where my computer is), instead of UTC time.

```
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import utc from 'dayjs/plugin/utc';
import timezone from 'dayjs/plugin/timezone';


dayjs.extend(utc);
dayjs.extend(timezone);


function TestPage() {
var dateString = "7/1/2023 08:04:09 AM";


var myDate = dayjs.utc(dateString);
var utcDateString = myDate.utc().format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss');
var formattedString = myDate.tz("America/New_York").format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss');  

console.log('utc string', utcDateString)
console.log('formatted string', formattedString)



console.log("====================================");
return (
    <div>
        <h1>{utcDateString}</h1>
        <h1>{formattedString}</h1>
    </div>
);
}

export default TestPage;
```

This function is logging the following:

```
utc string – "07/01/2023 12:04:09" 
formatted string – "07/01/2023 08:04:09"
```

As you can see, it's converting the string to UTC time, not the other way around. The result I expect is utcDateString to be the same as dateString and for formattedString to be 4:04:09 AM

Comment: Well the point is that the `.utc()` method is not documented as taking a date string as an argument. The implementation calls the standard constructor and sets the UTC flag, but as far as I can tell the date string is not parsed by the *new* dayjs object (the object with the utc flag).

Comment: Other than by providing it an ISO "Z" source date string, I can't figure out how to get it to parse an arbitrary format as a UTC date/time. If you change your input date string to ISO, you get the answers you expect.

Comment: I had to use .clone into a new date object and then it works

Comment: Don't use the *utc* method, you can [parse to a particular timezone or offset](https://day.js.org/docs/en/timezone/parsing-in-zone) with string + format if you've included the timezone and [*CustomParseFormat*](https://day.js.org/docs/en/plugin/custom-parse-format) plugins, e.g. `dayjs.tz(dateString, formatString, "Etc/UTC")`.

Answer (score 0):

**First of all, just let me clarify what I have understood from your question:**

1. `myDate` represent the date you convert from `dateString` base from your local timezone,
2. `utcDateString` represent the date you convert from `myDate` to utc date
3. `formattedString` represent the date from `myDate` converting to another time zone

**Here are my findings based on the issue you had:**

it looks like there is a specific format expected when we use `dayjs.utc` function, I am not 100% sure about the expected formats exactly are, but if we try to pass the format that we are using (in your case,it would be something like `DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss A`), by passing an extra parameter, we are able to let dayjs know more about the date that you want to convert into local time, `myDate`.

**Solution**

replace this line `var myDate = dayjs.utc(dateString);`  to be:

```
var inputDateFormat='DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss A';
var myDate = dayjs.utc(dateString,inputDateFormat);
```

Hope this would help!

Enjoy :)